# How to make the application screen appear when the screen is opened in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, screen, lockscreen, unlock

When the lock screen screen opens in Flutter, I want to launch and show my own app.

For example, an app will run on the screen that opens when I press the phone's unlock key. When the user selects the correct meaning of the English word in this application, the screen will open.

Actually what I want to ask is how can I check that the lock screen has been pressed?

I found Lock Screen plugins but they are only for creating a password lock screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into the [hardware_buttons](https://pub.dev/packages/hardware_buttons) package. With this package, you can detect the lock screen button pressed. But I'm not sure that there is a way to launch your app with these hardware buttons.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will examine the package. Can I run my application continuously in the background?

Comment: Yes, you can. Read more from this blog:    https://medium.com/vrt-digital-studio/flutter-workmanager-81e0cfbd6f6e

And you can look at the background_fetch package: https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

Comment: Thank you so much sir! ama gerçekten çok teşekkür ederim cevabınız için :)